# How do I add background gradients to a fragment.xml class

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, master-detail

Adding background gradients is a very basic thing I am aware but I am being thrown "the Markup in the document following the root element must be well formed"

I am certain I am doing something that is very obvious to many of you but if I can be shown the error of my ways here I will be grateful.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/articlelist"
android:name="com.MSmith.test.ArticleListFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
tools:context=".ArticleListActivity"
tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content"/>


<style android:background="#A9A9A9"/>
```

Tried adding the android:background="" into the  but as much as no errors were shown, the emulator/graphic showed no change.

Comment: `android:background="#A9A9A9"` to frament istself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a drawable like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="315"
        android:endColor="@color/mainMenuGradient_endColor"
        android:startColor="@color/mainMenuGradient_startColor" />

</shape>
```

and set this drawable as background in your fragments root layout, and you will have a gradient.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/articlelist"
android:name="com.MSmith.test.ArticleListFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
tools:context=".ArticleListActivity"
tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content"
android:background="@drawable/yourdrawablehere"/> <----- this might work
```

or add it directly in the xml-layout of the Fragment

Comment: Thankyou that was very prompt, but where is the fragments root layout located to, the drawable I have now placed into the application